# How to have compulsory login in asp.net for paticular page

Tags: asp.net

I have created default master page site with login and register option.

When you create default page you get three menu option i.e HOME ABOUTUS CONTACTUS.

I have added one more menu option i.e ADMIN.

whenever someone clicks ADMIN they are suppose to login mandatory.

How can I do it?

currently anyone can surf all menu pages without login.

I want to make it compulsory.

please help, basically I need member only page

Answer (score 0):

You can use the location config to specify the path of either a folder or page, see below for example and link to Microsoft details.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="https://myserver/mywebapp/secure/Login.aspx" 
               protection="All" 
               timeout="30" 
               name="AppNameCookie" 
               path="/FormsAuth" 
               requireSSL="true" 
               slidingExpiration="true" 
               defaultUrl="default.aspx"
               cookieless="UseCookies"
               enableCrossAppRedirects="false"/>
    </authentication>

    <!-- Deny access to unauthenticated users -->
    <authorization> 
       <deny users="?" />
       <allow users="*" />
     </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>

<!-- Allow unrestricted access to the folder with the login page -->
<location path="secure">
  <system.web>
    <authorization> 
       <allow users="*" />
     </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this section in your application `web.config` file, to deny access to all unauthenticated users to the location `admin_page.aspx`

```
   <configuration>
     <location path="admin_page.aspx">
      <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <deny users="?" /> 
        </authorization>
      </system.web>
     </location>
    </configuration>
```

Read [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871) for more information about *Control Authorization Permissions in an ASP.NET Application*